# Show Clicked Item details instead of whole array list

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I am making an event page in which I am showing an events in event-page successfully. Now i want to show the details of that particular clicked event in next page but right now it's showing whole events details in every event.

Here is my code done so far.

EventsPage.html

```
     <ion-content> 
     <ion-card *ngFor="let show of events" style="cursor:pointer">
<ion-list (click)="details()">
  <!--<ion-row>
    <ion-item style="cursor:pointer;border-bottom:1.5px solid #bbd164 !important">{{show.date}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-row>-->
  <ion-row style="border-bottom:1.5px solid #bbd164 !important">
    <ion-col col-7 style="cursor:pointer;color:#bbd164 !important;font-size: 12px;"><b>{{show.date}}</b></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-5 style="cursor:pointer;color:#bbd164 !important;font-size: 12px;"><b>{{show.timing}}</b></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-item style="cursor:pointer"><b>{{show.title}}</b></ion-item>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-item>{{show.description}}</ion-item>
  </ion-row>
   <ion-row>
     <ion-col col-6 padding style="color:#bbd164 !important"></ion-col>
     <ion-col col-1 ></ion-col>
    <ion-col  col-5 padding style="text-align: right;color:#bbd164 !important">{{show.category}}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-list>
</ion-card>
 </ion-content>
```

Here is my EventsPage.ts

```
export class EventsPage {
 index: any;
 categories_list: any;
 timeArray: any[];
 phone: any;
 pic_url: any;
 timing: any;
 category: any;
 email: any;
 description: any;
 website: any;
 address: any;
 title: any;
 date: any;
 events: any;
 selectOptions: { title: string; subTitle: string; mode: string; };
 readMoreFlag: boolean;
 noCategory: boolean;
 events_array: any;

 constructor(public http: Http, public ServerUrl: RemoteServiceProvider, 
  public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
   this.showEvents();

 }

showEvents() {
 this.ServerUrl.showEventDetails()
  .then(data => {
    this.events = data;
    console.log("events:", this.events);
    this.noCategory = false;
    this.events.forEach(element => {
      element.readMoreFlag = false;
      element.contentFlag = false;
      this.pic_url = element.pic_url;
      console.log("pic_url", this.pic_url);
    });

    this.timeArray = this.events;


  });

}

details(eventGet: any[]) {
  for (var value of this.events) {
  // console.log(value);
  console.log("1", value.pic_url);
  console.log("1", value.date);
  console.log("1", value.timing);
  console.log("1", value.address);
  console.log("1", value.description);
  console.log("1", value.phone);
  console.log("1", value.email);
  console.log("1", value.website);
}

this.navCtrl.push(EventsDetailPage, { });
// Here i want to push some clicked event details to show in next page.Like pic_url, title, address, phone etc. 
}


}
```

This code is successfully showing events in this page. Now i want to show details of particular clicked event in next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html :

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let show of events">
   <div (click)="details(show)"> details </div> 
</ion-card>
```

In component :

```
public details(selectedDetail:any){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedDetail)); 
}
```

Run code and check your console in browser.